# Tensorflow Session: Display the executed operations in session.run()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I was wondering if there is a way to display the executed steps/operations which are required for the current session run. So here is an simple example:

```
sum = tf.add(5, 3)
sum2 = tf.add(sum, 5)
sum3 = tf.add(3, 2)

with tf.Session()  as session:
   result = session.run(sum2) # steps: sum, sum2
   result2 = session.run(sum3) # steps: sum3
```

So I would like to print the steps required for `session.run(sum2)`, so that I can see that first `sum` is calculated. In case of `result2` no other operations are needed.

Can you help me?

Comment: Any ideas  or suggestions

Comment: One  way  could  be  to visualize  the graph, but  isn't  there  a function?